# Sum of the digits of an integer in lua

Tags: lua, integer, sum, addition, digits

I saw a question like this relating to Java and C, but I am using LUA. The answers might have applied to me, but I wasn't understanding them.

Could someone please tell me how I would get the sum of the individual digits of an Integer.
For Example.

```
a = 275
aSum = 2+7+5
```

If you could explain how I would achieve this in LUA and why the code does what it does, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really a simple function. Using gmatch will get you where you need to go.

```
function sumdigits(str)
  local total = 0
  for digit in string.gmatch(str, "%d") do
  total = total + digit
  end
  return total
end

print(sumdigits(1234))

10
```

Basically, you're looping through the integers and pulling them out one by one to add them to the total. The "%d" means just one digit, so string.gmatch(str, "%d") says, "Match one digit each time". The "for" is the looping mechanism, so for every digit in the string, it will add to the total.

Comment: Use `%d` instead of `.`?

Comment: Doh! I knew I was missing something, haha. Thanks, hjpotter92!

Comment: You weren't missing anything. Just that `%d` would only select the digits. As long as `sumdigits` gets numerical inputs, your `.` would have worked as well.

Comment: Yeah, I just meant missing something as in "There's an easier way to get just digits, can't remember it." I would have probably found it much later, but now don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this function:

```
function sumdigits(n)
   local sum = 0
   while n > 0 do
      sum = sum + n%10
      n = math.floor(n/10)
   end
   return sum
end
```

On each iteration it adds the last digit of n to the sum and then cuts it from n, until it sums all the digits.

Comment: +1. I don't know why people keep posting those 'convert it into a string and tostring each digit separately' methods; this is much more performant.

Answer (score 4):

`aSum = -load(('return'..a):gsub('%d','-%0'))()`

Comment: Good to see you finally posting answers instead of comments.

Comment: @hjpotter92 - It wouldn't last forever :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might get better performance than gmatch (not verified) with:

```
function sumdigits(str)
  local total = 0
  for i=1,#str do 
     total = total + tonumber(string.sub(str, i,i))
  end
  return total
end
print(sumdigits('1234'))
10
```