# How to work with integers in lua?

Tags: lua, int

So i have this number 1234567890 declared as this.

```
local num = 1234567890;
```

and now i what to add those numbers together 2+4+6+8+0 so would i go about this?

Comment: Can you please be elaborate? These seem to be two unrelated things.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum of the digits of an integer in lua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180828/sum-of-the-digits-of-an-integer-in-lua)

Comment: Why did you repeat yourself 3 times? Why do you say "I want to add *those* numbers" then give an example using different numbers?

Comment: If you want to add all the digits of `1234567890`, please say so. If not, please explain exactly what you're trying to do and clarify how it's related to `1234567890`. At stands now, `print(20)` would answer your question, but i don't think that's what you had in mind.

Comment: I want to add every second digit together.

Comment: "Every second digit" from the left? Or, the first, third, ... from the right? That would make a difference if there are an odd number of decimal digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
local num = 1234567890
local sum = 0
for a,b in tostring(num):gmatch("(.)(.)") do
    sum=sum+tonumber(b)
end
print(sum)
```